# Django Channels/Daphne Internal Server Error "'dict' object is not callable"

Tags: django, channel, daphne

I have received this Error when connecting to my site as it is running channels.

```
2018-03-25 20:59:19,049 - ERROR - http_protocol - Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/.virtualenvs/blog/lib/python3.5/site-packages/daphne/http_protocol.py", line 158, in process
"server": self.server_addr,
  File "/home/.virtualenvs/blog/lib/python3.5/site-packages/daphne/server.py", line 184, in create_application
application_instance = self.application(scope=scope)
  File "/home/.virtualenvs/blog/lib/python3.5/site-packages/channels/staticfiles.py", line 42, in __call__
return self.application(scope)
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
```

I have no idea where to start decoding the error. The channels server managed to start with this

```
Starting ASGI/Channels development server at http://0.0.0.0:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
2018-03-25 20:57:45,400 - INFO - server - HTTP/2 support not enabled (install the http2 and tls Twisted extras)
2018-03-25 20:57:45,400 - INFO - server - Configuring endpoint 
tcp:port=8000:interface=0.0.0.0
2018-03-25 20:57:45,401 - INFO - server - Listening on TCP address 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Comment: Can we see your routing.py file, as specified in the [channels installation guide?](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html)

Comment: did you solve this issue @Yalnix ?

Comment: Yes I did, eventually. I can't quite remember how, but it did involve a complete rework of the project.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem which caused the daphne server to crash in development.

```
File "C:\Users\sjsui\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers[base.py](base.py)", line 39, 
in load_middleware mw_instance = middleware(handler) 
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

I realised during installation of the channels package from pip, I had accidentally added a bad middleware in `settings.MIDDLEWARE`:

[image]

After removing this line `django.middleware` I was able to start the development server again.

Answer (score 1):

not sure if it's still relevant, but for others to see I figured this out today.

When configuring the new environment upon upgrading Django I created an asgi.py file with

```
 application = 'whatever.module.application'
```

In my case the error message was "str" object not callable.

So I did a bit of thinking (as a direct answer to this problem was nowhere to be found and I almost posted on stack ;)) and figured that the applications variable needs to be the actual router instance.

In my case I use a protocol router as I need both websockets and normal HTTP. Looking into the code earlier on, http_protocol.py handles it internally ("# BORING old HTTP" is one comment in there. lol.)

```
application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    "websocket": urls.urlpatterns
})
```

and then urls.urlpatterns might contain something like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
  url(r'^', include('cars.urls', namespace='cars')),
  url(r'^help/', include('help.urls', namespace='help'))
]
```

I'm guessing your problem was to use something similar what is in urlpatterns above directly as

```
...
application = []
...
```

trust that helps someone out there with the same problem.

Comment: do you mean, we have to the use the url patterns directly?
as in point the application without AuthMiddlewareStack

Comment: well in my case that's how it worked. 
I'm not saying it's impossible to include auth middleware

@SanjeevSiva, do you have an exact problem which I might look at?